# Getting error in Nodemailer if recipient email is wrong

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, nodes, nodemailer

I am sending an email With Nodemailer SMTP

Its working fine if email account is valid / existing, But getting an 500 error when entering email address whic is not exist.

I know it is not sending because email not exist but need to handle errors

I have also tried `tls: {rejectUnauthorized: false},` but getting same issue

I am using Custom SMTP not using Gmail SMTP

My code is as below:

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                host: 'smtp.myhost.de',
                port: 587,
                auth: {
                  user: 'CUSTOM_SMTP_EMAIL', // generated ethereal user
                  pass: 'CUSTOM_SMTP_PASS' // generated ethereal password
                },
                secure:false,
                requireTLS: false,
                tls: {rejectUnauthorized: false},
                debug:true
              });



let info = await transporter.sendMail({
                from: sails.config.custom.appName+ SENDER_EMAIL, // sender address
                to: inputs.email, // list of receivers
                subject: "My email subject ", // Subject line
                text: "Verify Email Address "+inputs.email, // plain text body
                html: html // html body
              },function(err) {
                console.log('email sent');

                if (err){
                    console.log( 'err->>>>>>>>>>>>>', err);
                    return exits.success('error');

                } else {
                   console.log('success');
                   return exits.success('success');
                }
              });
```

I am not able to return `return exits.success('error');` because of 500 error.

Getting below error

err->>>>>>>>>>>>>

```
{ Error: Can't send mail - all recipients were rejected: 552 5.2.2 host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [2a00:1450:400c:c09::1a] said: The email account that you tried to reach is over quota. Please direct the recipient to https://support.google.com/mail/?p=OverQuotaPerm q13si8918761wrn.204 - gsmtp (H-QUOTA)
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (/var/www/html/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:784:19)
    at SMTPConnection._actionRCPT (/var/www/html/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1613:28)
    at SMTPConnection._responseActions.push.str (/var/www/html/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1566:30)
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (/var/www/html/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:942:20)
    at SMTPConnection._onData (/var/www/html/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:749:14)
    at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketData.chunk (/var/www/html/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:195:44)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:607:20)
  code: 'EENVELOPE',
  response: '552 5.2.2 host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [2a00:1450:400c:c09::1a] said: The email account that you tried to reach is over quota. Please direct the recipient to https://support.google.com/mail/?p=OverQuotaPerm q13si8918761wrn.204 - gsmtp (H-QUOTA)',
  responseCode: 552,
  command: 'RCPT TO',
  rejected: [ 'jay@gmail.com' ],
  rejectedErrors:
   [ { Error: Recipient command failed: 552 5.2.2 host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [2a00:1450:400c:c09::1a] said: The email account that you tried to reach is over quota. Please direct the recipient to https://support.google.com/mail/?p=OverQuotaPerm q13si8918761wrn.204 - gsmtp (H-QUOTA)
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (/var/www/html/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:784:19)
    at SMTPConnection._actionRCPT (/var/www/html/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1599:24)
    at SMTPConnection._responseActions.push.str (/var/www/html/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1566:30)
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (/var/www/html/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:942:20)
    at SMTPConnection._onData (/var/www/html/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:749:14)
    at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketData.chunk (/var/www/html/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:195:44)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:607:20)
       code: 'EENVELOPE',
       response: '552 5.2.2 host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [2a00:1450:400c:c09::1a] said: The email account that you tried to reach is over quota. Please direct the recipient to https://support.google.com/mail/?p=OverQuotaPerm q13si8918761wrn.204 - gsmtp (H-QUOTA)',
       responseCode: 552,
       command: 'RCPT TO',
       recipient: 'jay@gmail.com' } ] }
```

Answer (score 1):

If callback is not passed as a second argument to `sendMail`, it returns a promise that can be awaited:

```
let info = await transporter.sendMail({
    from: sails.config.custom.appName+ SENDER_EMAIL, // sender address
    to: inputs.email, // list of receivers
    subject: "My email subject ", // Subject line
    text: "Verify Email Address "+inputs.email, // plain text body
    html: html // html body
}).then(() => {
    console.log('success');
    return exits.success('success');
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log( 'err->>>>>>>>>>>>>', err);
    return exits.success('error');
});

console.log(info);
```

Comment: thanks @antonku, it returning `error` and i make condition based on that, but does anyway that nodemailer does not give any error if email is invalid. is that possible  ?

Comment: @DevsiOdedra I am sorry for the confusion, you don't have to promisify sendMail as it returns a promise if callback is not passed by default. Updated the answer. I don't think that I get the second question though. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: thanks for the time and effort @antonku, i mean that if i enter the email which is not exist, if some user come and signup with fake mail then currently getting errors which i mention in question, so is there any settings in nodemailer which stop the error event if entered email not exist?? this thing is related nodemailer because sails js helper working fine with your answer.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. Unfortunately, I failed to find an option that would suppress such errors in `nodemailer`. However, you may want to inspect the error object instead. The error object has `code`, `response` and `responseCode` properties so that you probably can distinguish errors using those properties and handle them appropriately.

Comment: Everytime I try to send email with wrong email ID , i get response as message Queued. is there nay way to catch that error?